# GtkD with D lang on Fedora

Tags: gtk, d, pony, gtkd

I use Fedora20 and I install gtkd via 
sudo yum install gtkd

How to compile gtk this code ?

```
import gtk.MainWindow;
import gtk.Label;
import gtk.Main;

void main(string[] args)
{
    Main.init(args);
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow("Hello World");
    win.setDefaultSize(200, 100);
    win.add(new Label("Hello World"));
    win.showAll();
    Main.run();
}
```

but i get this error

➜  /tmp  dmd -L-lgtkd -L-ldl main.d
   main.d(1): Error: module MainWindow is in file 'gtk/MainWindow.d' which cannot be read
   import path[0] = /usr/include/dmd/phobos
   import path[1] = /usr/include/dmd/druntime/import

Please help me.

Comment: Your import path doesn't include the folder where gtkd lives. I don't know where the package puts it, but if you can find that, add -I/whatever/that/is to the compile command line (it should the gtkd folder that contains a gtk folder) and something should change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `gtkd-devel` package provided by Fedora, you should know that it is linked against `libphobos-ldc` library which you will get once you install `ldc2` package (`yum install ldc2` will do).

This does not yet solve your problem though... gtkd-devel package installs gtkd D interface modules into the `/usr/include/d/gtkd-2` folder. So, in order to compile your GtkD application you need to execute something like (assuming your D file has name "firstwin.d"): `ldc2 -I/usr/include/d/gtkd-2 -L-lgtkd-2 firstwin.d`