# Plot2kill won't compile on Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, compilation, d, gtkd

I'm trying to follow the instructions for compiling Plot2kill as given [here](https://github.com/dsimcha/Plot2kill). I used `yaourt` to install GtkD, so I know I definitely have the library. However, when I try

```
dmd -lib -ofplot2kill.lib -O -inline -release *.d
```

I get the following error message:

```
subplot.d(437): Error: module DrawingArea is in file 'gtk/DrawingArea.d' which cannot be read
import path[0] = /usr/include/dlang/dmd
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell DMD where to find GtkD files. The easiest way is to use the `-I` parameter. Example: `-I/usr/include/d/gtk-d`. 
Your command line should be something like: `dmd -lib -ofplot2kill.lib -O -inline -release -I/usr/include/d/gtk-d -L-lgtkd-2 *.d`

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546459/876497) on StackOverflow.